# How to let the insertion operator << use my string conversion?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

My class defines a conversion operator:

```cpp
class A{
public:
    operator string(){
        return "AAA";
    }
};

// I don't want to overload this one
// ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, A&){ 
//     return os << "BBB";
// }

int main() {
    A a;
    string s(a);
    cout<<s;
    cout<<a;
}
```

I want the insertion operator to implicitly convert `a` into `string` before sending it to output. But the compiler refuses:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'A')
     cout<<a;
     ~~~~^~~
```

followed by a bunch of failed attempts to convert `a` to some type I don't expect.

How can I let it know to try the `string` type?

Comment: Why don't you want the overload?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful:  cout<<string(a);

Comment: Try this: `operator const char*(){ return "AAA"; }`.

Comment: Try `typeid(s).name()` and `typeid(a).name()`. There are different.

Comment: @Ruks: Why can't it deduce std::string for cout? But fine for const char*?

Comment: @InQusitive Because `std::string` isn't a part of  the [overloads of `std::ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) but `const char*` is.

Comment: @Ruks: Thanks, Never knew.  And jerror: thanks for the question :-)

Comment: @Ruks: I think you should make this an answer. Also if someone can explain why std::string is not a part of std::ostream::operator<<, it would be good.

Comment: @Ruks "*Because `std::string` isn't a part of the overloads of `std::ostream::operator<<`*" - not as a member overload, no. But there is a [non-member overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: @jerron "*I don't want to overload [operator<<]*" - why? You did not explain your reason. Overloading the operator is the correct way to stream custom types. There is nothing stopping your overload from using your conversion operator internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, I should've added that implicit user-defined conversions do not work for function templates and the non-member overload of `std::string` uses function templates in the second operand while `const char*` overload doesn't. If we add something like `void operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const std::string& rhs) { lhs << &rhs[0]; }` then in that case too the program will compile. (since it eliminates the template.)

Comment: why cout<<s works, given " std::string isn't a part of the overloads of std::ostream::operator<<" ? @Ruks

Comment: @jerron Because `std::string` is essentially just `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`, so doing operator << which invokes the [first non-member overload of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).